# JSON (AJAX) update of ActionText fails on Rails 6.1 RC1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, trix, actiontext

I have a basic web app with a form using `ActionText`. When changes are made, a have a Trix listener that calls my controller via AJAX (autosave!). The controller looks like this:

```rb
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @model.update(model_params)
        format.json { render json: @model }
      else
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This was working absolutely fine on Rails 6.1 alpha, but since the [update to Rails 6.1 RC1](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/b5b078cd99b0107fd8e31ff619578e5321182e0a...3baf25e1192df36db99162884b5c115db04dd0a3) the same code results in this error:

```rb
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial action_text/content/_layout with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]}.
```

Is anyone able to shed any light on why this might be? I have tried digging through the source but I'm none the wiser. I wondered also whether it was related to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39266).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem as follows. Originally I had `format: :json` in the `form_with` declaration:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: @model, format: :json) do |form| %>
```

This was working in Rails 6.1 Alpha but not in RC1. Removing the format from the code solved the issue.

```rb
<%= form_with(model: @model) do |form| %>
```

The POST request now comes through as JS not JSON and this makes the problem go away.

```rb
Processing by MyController#update as JS
```